# Best way of writing subroutines in 6502 Assembler?

Tags: assembly, calling-convention, 6502, c64

I'm new to assemblers, so here is a simple question:

My custom subroutines change the `X`, `Y`, and `A` registers. They manipulate these to produce the desired results. Is it a good idea to push these values to the stack when the routine starts and restore them before `RTS`?

I mean, this way I can write routines which can be called from anywhere without messing up the "state" or affecting other routines. But is it OK to use the stack this way? Or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: It all depends on what calling convention you want to implement. If you define that your function overwrites a certain register, and you can write all callers so as to take this into account, you can make the choice either way.

Comment: It is common on older machines to use a custom and potentially different calling convention for each function based on both its signature (parameters & return value) and internal implementation -- this is practical when programming in assembly, and gets more difficult in C.

Comment: In C64 it makes typically sense to use fixed addresses in zero page for passing some parameters, especially 16-bit addresses.

Comment: There's quite a few ways to do it. Pushing is totally fine. Here's a good read for you. https://wilsonminesco.com/stacks/

Answer (score 5):

> But is it OK to use the stack this way? Or is there a better way to do this?

Absolutely; BASIC does it all the time, as do many routines in the kernal.

But, there is no *right* answer to this, it comes down to at least speed, portability, and style.

- If you use the stack a lot, there are some speed considerations.  Your typical `pha` `txa` `pha` `tya` `pha` at the start, and then the reverse (`pla` `tay` `pla` `tax` `pla`) eats up 3 bytes of your stack, and adds in some cycle time due to the 2 x 5 operations
- You could use zero page, but that takes away some portability between different machines; VIC-20, C64, C128, the free zero page addresses may not be the same across platforms.  And your routine can't be called "more than once" without exiting first (e.g. no recursion) because if it is called while it is active, it will overwrite zero page with new values.  But, you don't need to use zero page...
- ...because you can just create your own memory locations as part of your code:

  ```
  myroutine = *
      ; do some stuff..
      rts

  mymem =*
      .byt 0, 0, 0
  ```
- the downside to this is that your routine can only be called "once", otherwise subsequent calls will overwrite your storage areas (e.g. no recursion allowed!!, same problem as before!)
- You could write your own mini-stack

  ```
    put_registers =*
       sei ; turn off interrupts so we make this atomic
       sty temp
       ldy index
       sta a_reg,y
       stx x_reg,y
       lda temp
       sta y_reg,y
       inc index
       cli
       rts

    get_registers =*
       sei ; turn off interrupts so we make this atomic
       dec index
       ldy index
       lda y_reg,y
       sta temp
       lda a_reg,y
       ldx x_reg,y
       ldy temp
       cli
       rts

    a_reg .buf 256
    x_reg .buf 256
    y_reg .buf 256
    index .byt 0
    temp  .byt 0
  ```
- This has the added benefit that you now have 3 virtual stacks (one for each of `.A`, `.X`, `.Y`), but at a cost (not exactly a quick routine).  And because we are using `SEI` and `CLI`, you may need to re-think this if doing it from an interrupt handler.  But this also keeps the "true" stack clean and more than triples your available space.